# selecting a cell of a column using select () function

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny

For the code below, I need to select the first row of the data frame.

```
    IDD_mapdata_1 <- reactive ({
    IDD_nhmap$race_black <- round(IDD_nhmap$race_black, 1)
    out_map_1 <- IDD_nhmap %>%
      filter (ProjectID %in% input$Disability_map)
    return(out_map_1)
    #list(cat)
  })
```

Comment: The first row can be returned with `%>% slice(1)`

Comment: I forgot about slice, this is another good way to do it.

You can do this for a specific value in the dataframe:
`df %>% slice(1) %>% pull('Age')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the first row only of the dataframe you could do this:

```
head(out_map_1) or out_map_1[1,]
```

This gives you the dataframe headers if you want just the row as a vector of strings, or numbers just wrap this. For example, if you need just a :

```
as.character(out_map_1[1,])
```

[image]

To get a specific value from the select statement you can do something like this:

```
df[1,] %>% select('Age') %>% pull()
```

[image]